# Angular-chart.js not displaying unit in Y axis

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, chart.js

I have a chart, using [angular-chart.js](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/), which the x and y axis values varies depending on which item a user clicks on. When one of the items is clicked, it omits the first unit so instead of displaying `2.52` it displays `.52`. If you see below, the log is showing the correct information, just not displaying it.
[image: error with chart.js graph]

The website I have provided a link to above provides examples which I have followed and I am a bit stumped why this is happening. It is quite lengthy my code for populting the chart with the correct data but I will try and provide only the necessary code.

Any ideas why the correct value isn't being displayed in the Y axis?

**service which gathers the data for the graph**

```
app.factory('loadPatentItemService', ['$http', '$timeout', function($http, $timeout) {

    var factory = {};

        var selectedData = null;
        var selectedLabel = null;
        var selectedItem = null;
        var REST_SERVICE_URI = '../json/cost-data.json';

        //function is invoked from the view and data is passed depending which item was clicked

        factory.select = function(item) { 
            selectedItem = item;
            factory.getPatent();
            return [selectedItem];
        }

        factory.getPatent =  function() {
            var itemId = [];
            itemId.push(selectedItem.id)

            $http.get(REST_SERVICE_URI)
            .then(function(response){

                var items = response.data.dataset; 

                var graphData = [];
                var graphLabel = [];

                for (i = 0;i < items.length; i++) {
                    if(items[i].id == itemId) {

                        graphData.push(items[i].data);
                        graphLabel.push(items[i].label);
                        factory.graphLabel(graphLabel);
                        factory.graphData(graphData);
                    }
                }    
            }), 
            function(errResponse) {
                console.log('error')
            }

            return selectedItem;

        }

        factory.graphData = function(data) {
            selectedData = data;
            return [data];
        }

        factory.graphLabel = function(label) {
            selectedLabel = label;
            return [label];
        }

        factory.getData = function() {
            return selectedData;
        }

        factory.getLabel = function() {
            return selectedLabel;
        }        

    return factory;

}])
```

---

**graph controller**

```
app.controller("lineCtrl", ['$scope', '$timeout', 'loadPatentItemService', function ($scope, $timeout, loadPatentItemService) {

    var initGraph = loadPatentItemService.getPatent();
    var getGraphData = loadPatentItemService.getData();
    var getGraphLabel = loadPatentItemService.getLabel();

    $scope.labels = getGraphLabel[0];
    $scope.data = getGraphData[0];
    console.log(getGraphData[0], getGraphLabel[0])

    $scope.datasetOverride = [{ yAxisID: 'y-axis-1' }, { yAxisID: 'y-axis-2' }];
    $scope.options = {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [
                {
                  id: 'y-axis-1',
                  type: 'linear',
                  display: true,
                  position: 'left'
                },
                {
                  id: 'y-axis-2',
                  type: 'linear',
                  display: true,
                  position: 'right'
                }
            ]
        }
    };
}])
```